# WCF service from existing WSDL

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I'm trying to create a new service based on an existing wsdl. I was able to add a service reference to the wsdl and implement it in my svc file. I'm not getting the following error - 'The contract '' does not match the name in service contract or there is no valid methods in this contrct. I'm only creating the service application at this point. There is no client.

Comment: "I'm **not** getting the following error" - is that meant to be "I'm **now** getting the following error? :)

Comment: Please post your web.config and the markup in the .svc file.

Comment: And while you're at it - please also post the service contract (the interface)